# Python list and type error

Tags: python, list, exception, types

I've code this code in Python:

```
if type(data).__name__=='list':
                print type(data).__name__
                print ",".join(data)
```

And it give me this error:

```
    print ",".join(data)
exceptions.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

How's that possible?!?

Thanks in advance for anyhelp.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have a list of lists. Try:

```
",".join(str(x) for x in data)
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.join()` can only join a sequence of strings.  Obviously your list contains an item that itself is a list again.

Furthermore, if you really need to check for the type of an object, a better way to do it is

```
if isinstance(data, list):
    ...
```

Comment: yeah... i'm so dumb... my list contains some lists to... sorry to bother you all. but thanks anyway for the tip about isinstance

Answer (score 0):

The first element of `data` is a `list`. It must be a string in order for `str.join()` to work as shown. In fact, all elements must.

Answer (score 0):

Don't explicitly check for types. If you do need to, use [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance).

The error is appearing because of the contents of `data` rather than its type. It needs to be a list of strings for the `str.join` method to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of your list is also a list, not a string.

Also you don't have to do `type(data).__name__=='list'` - just `type(data) is list`

Even better - just check with `isinstance` since you don't really care about a specific type in most cases.

Comment: `s/Even better - .*/Even better - just don't check types at all./` ;)

Answer (score 0):

`join` expects an iterable of *strings*. What seems to happen in your case is that the first element of your list is another list. This is what's causing the error.

As an aside, the `if type(data).__name__=='list': ...` is as un-Pythonic as code gets.